# Global Error Handler In Provider and Services

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular8, angular-services

I've got an error service setup in Angular 8 that is handling all errors that come from components as I expect - logging to the console and not throwing any additional errors.

```
import { Injectable, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core'

@Injectable()
export class ErrorService implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor() { }
  handleError(error) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', error.message);
  }
}
```

But in the DocumentService (anything listed in providers) if an error gets thrown it will occasionally go through the ErrorService but usually it doesn't hit that code.

```
  providers: [
    ErrorService
    , {
      provide: ErrorHandler,
      useClass: ErrorService,
    }
    , DocumentService
    ],
```

The DocumentService is injected into components like this

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('pdfViewer', { static: false }) public pdfViewer;
  @ViewChild('claimPdfViewer', { static: false }) public claimPdfViewer;

  selectedElements: HTMLElement[] = [];

  constructor(private documentService: DocumentService) {
...
```

What do I need to do to get the DocumentService (and anything else in providers) to always use my ErrorService or is there some other way to globally handle the errors from services?

EDIT:
The global event handler is only not getting reached when the exception happens in an observable subscription or event handler

```
    this.traceService.onHighlightTrace.subscribe(traces => {
      if (traces != this.documentService.searchTraces) {
        this.documentService.clearAllPagesOfAllHighlights();
        //exception gets thrown in this.clearAllPagesOfAllHighlights(); and there is 
// no try/catch in there so I would expect the exception to get caught by the handler.
        //instead exception never goes to the global error handler and just 
//gets logged to the console as uncaught
        ....
```

EDIT 2: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/globalerror-handler

This replicates the event getting unhooked on error.  It does not replicate the global event handler not handling the the error though....

Comment: You don't need to declare the `DocumentService` as a provider, you can use in `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})`. Maybe that's causing this.

Comment: @JorgeMussato - thanks.  I gave that a shot but it didn't change the functionality - errors in the DocumentService still aren't hitting the ErrorService (usually, they do once every 5 or 6 errors)

Comment: Doesn't sound right. We have this set up as well like you, and I can assure you that all errors are going through the Error service unless you are handling them in a try catch block. If angular for any reason throws an error, it will go there.

Comment: @IvanMihaylov - I agree.  But in the console I see this document.service.ts:405 Uncaught TypeError: this.foo is not a function.  Also if I had a try/catch somewhere the service wouldn't be crashing (not responding), which it does after a few of these.

Comment: Can you provide which function throws an error please?

Comment: Sure.  I think you're onto something because I discovered it only happens inside event handlers like this: ```this.documentService.frameDoc.addEventListener('textlayerrendered', (evt: CustomEvent) => {
            documentService.mapSpans(evt.detail.pageNumber);
        });```I'd like to not have to try/catch all them.  I also noticed the globalevent handler doesn't work in subscribe methods - the exception gets caught but I end up unsubscribed.

Comment: @JorgeMussato - All my testing is only showing a problem if the error comes in an event handler or subscription.  Not sure why or how to handle that - is there a way besides putting try/catch in each event handler/subscription?

Comment: I didn't quite understand where you get errors. If you could provide a code example would be great.

Comment: @JorgeMussato Here is an example of where I get an exception thrown that does not get caught in the global handler: ```this.traceService.onHighlightTrace.subscribe(traces => {
      if (traces != this.documentService.searchTraces) {
        this.documentService.clearAllPagesOfAllHighlights(); //exception thrown here there is no try/catch in clearAllPagesOfAllHighlights() ....}   ```

Comment: Add it to your question, it's not readable in the comments section

Comment: @JorgeMussato - done.  Thanks!

Comment: I can't locate the error sorry. Maybe if you can build a stackblitz replicating so I can try to manipulate. ;)

Comment: @JorgeMussato.  Here is a stack blitz that replicates one of the problems:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/globalerror-handler  As I would expect the global error handler gets hit on each error but if the error happens in the subscription it only happens once.

Comment: The mistake is not in the error handler, it is in the call of the function. It's not even calling the service function (`console.log` it to see).

Comment: @JorgeMussat - triggerUnhandledError gets called every time you click 'Trigger Unhandled Error'.  The first time you click it you see in the log 'Got it: ReferenceError: y is not defined'.  Every other time you click it you don't see that message.  Why?

Comment: Because the first time it hits the `service`, the second time it doesn´t hit. I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: @JorgeMussato I updated the stackblitz.  Logging now shows that the service is getting called on subsequent tries, it's the subscription that only gets hit once.